# Webform form alter date hide day

Tags: date, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform, drupal-hooks

I'm relatively new to Drupal 7 and I'm trying to create a custom webform. My goal is to add a date (provided by the date module) field with out the day option. So it displays on month and year hiding the day option.

I have managed to achieve this but only by recreating the wholedate field as a custom field but I wanted to know if it was possible to customize the date field provided by the date module.

Below is a screen shot of my form: [image]

How I create my custom date field:

```
function my_webform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

      if (isset($form['#node']->webform) && $form['#node']->uuid == '00b20537-d5ce-45c2-af37-150c9e73b96d') {

           //$form['submitted']['date']['#type'] = 'hidden';

           $form['ggg'] = array(
            '#type' => 'date_select',
            '#title' => 'Date',
            '#date_format' => 'm/Y',
            '#default_value' => date('Y-m-d')
          );


      }
    }
```

I have tried other methods on hiding the field components but nothing seem to work so far. I was wondering if I needed to implement a hook different from the alter hook (the one being used).

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: I think it is during the date field creation in your form that you have to specify only month and year. By default, it collect year, month, day, hours and minutes. You can uncheck all but year and month and I think it would solve your problem. Tell me if it will.

Comment: This is a good solution for when you create a content type. These configuration options are not available when adding a date component to a webform

Comment: And what about creating a new custom date format in configuration -> regional -> date time -> format with only month and year ? Can you call this in your '#type' key ?

Comment: No, this is not picked up when adding a new component to a webfrom

Comment: Ok. I'm pretty new to Drupal too. But I see you've got a correct answer by someone else and you've found out how to solve your problem! I'm relieved for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to transform the `day` field of the date component to a `hidden` field instead of the `select` field type. That can be achieved by adding a `#process` callback for that field and altering the data.

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    // Your logic here depending which form to alter
    // ...

    // Add #process for the component with key name 'date'
    $form['submitted']['date']['#process'][] = 'YOURMODULE_process_date';
}

function YOURMODULE_process_date(&$element)
{
    // change type to hidden
    $element['day']['#type'] = 'hidden';

    // set value to first day of the month
    $element['day']['#value'] = '1';

    return $element;
}
```

Comment: yep exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Webform now allows hiding the day, month or year of a date. See [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/336150) for details.